# quadratic form and bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been solving exercise problems of Linear Algebra by Friedberg where I need to label the statements as either true or false. There is one statement in exercise 6.8
" every quadratic form is a bilinear form"

I labeled it "true" as every quadratic form is associated with some symmetric bilinear form, but it is a wrong statement according to the solution given in the same book.

I know that a symmetric bilinear form is diagonalizable in a vector space over the field not of characteristic two.

Should I use this concept? I am quite confused now. please help me to clear this concept.

Comment: a quadratic form is a mapping $\phi: V\longrightarrow \mathbb F$ and a bilinear form is a mapping $\psi: V\times V\longrightarrow \mathbb F$.  The Domains are different so a quadratic form cannot be a bilinear form.

Comment: A symmetric bilinear  form H(x,y)=H(y,x)= becomes quadratic if x=y, i.e., H(x,x) is a quadratic form.